# Selectively dumping and inserting into new database with a new primary key

Tags: database, import, mysql

I have a database has been running on a server. I also have a database running for about a month on a new server which has data based on the old server. Since these both have been running this past month, the data on them are not equal.

We want to move selective data from two tables in the old database to the new one. This is the select I want to move, one month of data:

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.keyID = table2.keyID 
where table2.updated between '2013-08-01' and '2013-08-31';
```

From my understanding I would probably need to dump each table on its own. However when inserting this data into the new database, I would need to give these entries new keyID (this is autogenerated). How can I do this while keeping the connection between these two tables?

Comment: Just to check if I understand correctly: you have already managed to dump/import the data to the new server, filter out the duplicates and only need to merge the tables while preserving the relation between table1 and table2?

Answer (score 0):

Take a dump of **table1** & **table2** from the **old server** and restore it in the **new server** under the database name  **oldDB**

I Assume your database name in new server is **newdb**

```
Insert into newdb.table1 (Field1,Field2,field3)
select    Field1,Field2,field3 
from      olddb.table1 
left join olddb.table2 
on        (olddb.table1.keyID = olddb.table2.keyID)
Where     olddb.table2.updated between '2013-08-01' and '2013-08-31';
```

Please note that you have to specify all the fields in select statement except your **KeyID** field. **KeyID** number will be autogenerated by the database

I am assuming that the **KeyID** Field is **Auto Increment field** other wise this solution will not work